# What is this grounding connector for devices called?

Tags: connector, identification, grounding

I need to find the grounding connector/socket (male) like in the photo for my device, but cannot find what it is exactly called or if it is rather something custom-made.

[image: Photo of connector]

Comment: https://www.iso.org/obp/ui#iec:grs:60417:5021

Comment: Arsenii - if you are intending to use equipment such as connectors and wires in a regulated enviroment, such as a hospital, you may have to comply with colour and other specifications, including DIN 42801 compliance.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey yes, thank you for this note! We are developing now a unit for medical endoscopy and have to compy to all the crossing standards. Thank you!

Comment: If you are developing for medical work you should know all this already.

Comment: It is a EN60601 requirement for all medical equipment sold in Europe.  Other international medical standards allow a different connector but this one is accepted in any country.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

[image]

**POAG  Potentialausgleich (German: Potential Equalization)**

POAG connectors are used for connecting items together for grounding and potential equalisation purposes, often in hospital and laboratory environments, and there is a European standard: DIN 42801, recognised worldwide.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Stäubli POAG connector.
For more detailled information on the product, refer to the catalogue:
https://ec.staubli.com/AcroFiles/Catalogues/ME_Med-Main-11014109_(en)_hi.pdf
or visit the website
[www.staubli.com/electrical](http://www.staubli.com/electrical)